# Pairwise independence implies independence for classes on susbsets of a probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, independence

Let $(\mathcal{C}_i)_{i\in I}$ be pairwise independent classes of the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$, i.e. $\mathcal{C}_i,~\mathcal{C}_j$ are independent for every $i\neq j$ in $I$. True or false:  $(\mathcal{C}_i)_{i\in I}$ are independent.

My thoughts: i strongly believe that this is false (we should have had independence for every finite subfamily). I am trying to find a counterexample, looking of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ and three sets $A,~B,~C$ that are pairwise independent but are not independent (favorably, $A\cap B\cap C=\emptyset$).

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed wrong.

Assume you throw two independent coins. Let $X$ resp. $Y$ be $1$ if the first resp. second coin toss shows heads and $0$ otherwise. Then define $Z = I\{X = Y\}$. Now the random variables $X, Y, Z$ [and therefore their induced $\sigma$-algebras] are pairwise independent, but not jointly independent.

Comment: Nice example @Dominik. Thanks a lot!